# Accessibility Warning by Google Play Pre-Launch report

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android, google-play-console

I have developed an Android game using **Cocos2d-X 3.16**. The game is uploaded in open beta. Recently, I reviewed the **pre-launch report** on **Google Play Console**. The report was showing following warning for the game **splash screen** (created using sprite) under “**Accessibility**” section:

```
This item may not have a label readable by screen readers.
```

I have following questions:

1. How can I fix this warning?
2. Is there a way to provide Android style **content description** field in Cococs-2DX?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Why down vote? Any problem with the post content or formatting?

Comment: I encountered the same issue. have you solve this?

Comment: If you are using cocos2d-x engine, then this issue is expected and there is no solution to it.